# Former slave girl repeats a message subliminally implanted by a former soldier and eventually joins the army

Tags: story-identification

I need help finding the name of a book I read a few years ago please.
I had thought it was a David Weber book but if it is I still haven't found it.

The prologue starts on a slave planet that is being liberated by allied forces and at the sight of a particular uniform a slave girl starts repeating a message that had been subliminally planted by another slave that was an allied forces officer before he died. The girl goes on to join the allied army herself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the book you are looking for is *Sassinak* by Anne McCaffrey and Elizabeth Moon, part of a trilogy called *[Planet Pirates](http://www.elizabethmoon.com/books-planetpirates.html)*, which is in turn linked to the *[Dinosaur Planet](http://mccaffrey.srellim.org/series/dpp-intro.htm)* books.

Sassinak is a young girl on a colony planet who is captured and enslaved by pirates, only to be rescued finally and given a chance to join the military. She rises through the ranks to become commander of a cruiser with a burning desire to eliminate such pirates from the universe. It is her cruiser that rescues the survivors of the heavyworlder mutiny on the dinosaur planet.

The message is implanted in Sassinaks mind by another slave called Abe, who is rescued, but then later killed.